# Cordova orientation plugin works fine in emulator but doesn’t work in real phone(test in ionic view)

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-view

**Update**:
I took a look at the ionic view documents and got the answer: ionic view only support a list of limitied 3rd plugins. This is not a good question. I will read the doc more carefully before starting useing it.

I am using Cordova orientation plugin, when the orientation changes, the UI will change accordingly. It works well in an emulator, but when I test it in ionic view(ios version) it doesn't work. the UI which should have been changed didn't change a little. 
How to solve this? btw, I am not using ngCordova, just Cordova plugin.

Comment: you can't use 3rd party plugins on ionic view

Comment: I checked the doc showing ionic view only supports a list of limited plugins. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try adding ` <preference name="orientation" value="portrait"/>` in your config.xml and test it

Answer (score 0):

In your config.xml file, in platform ios configs, add `<preference name="Orientation" value="all"/>` and test again.

Comment: it doesn't work:( since it can work in emulator, I think the config file is fine.

Comment: Its a stupid question but, your device are able to rotate?

Comment: it did rotate. just cannot see any changes of UI. but the same thing works on emulator...

Comment: Check if your plugin version is supported by ionic view http://docs.ionic.io/v1.0/docs/view-usage

Comment: You can check if have any issue with orientation in ionic view https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-view-issues/issues

Comment: And i recommend you to test in Android device too

Comment: I checked the doc showing ionic view only supports a list of limited plugins. Thanks for your help.